# How to detect `onClickOutside` and `onEscapeKeyPress` in custom React modal created as a styled component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, styled-components

Now, I've spent considerable amount of time on this. But, I'm not able to figure it out as I am new to using [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/).

I've created a Modal styled component in React. The only thing left to be done is adding 'onClickOutside' and 'onEscapeKeyPress' functionality.

But, for the life of me, I'm not able to add the event listeners to the Modal element (nor to the underlying `div` element).

[**Here's a link to codesandbox demo**](https://codesandbox.io/s/6yn8p455wk)

Here's the ideal way I'd like the user to use my component:

```
<Modal
    show={this.state.isOpen}
    onBackgroundClick={this.toggleModal}
    onEscapeKeydown={this.toggleModal}
    >
    <Modal.Wrapper>
        <Modal.Header>
            <!-- ignore this -->
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
            <!-- ignore this -->
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
            <!-- ignore this -->
        </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal.Wrapper>
</Modal>
```

**OR**

```
<Modal
    show={this.state.isOpen}
    closeOnEscape
    closeOnClickOutside
    >
    <Modal.Wrapper>
        <Modal.Header>
            <!-- ignore this -->
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
            <!-- ignore this -->
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
            <!-- ignore this -->
        </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal.Wrapper>
</Modal>
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I was waiting for some assistance from the SO community, I managed to find a solution myself.

To put it briefly for the ones who, like me, are relatively new to using styled components: A Styled component is just that, a 'styled' component. You cannot overload it with any script. In order to detect `onClickOutside` and `onEscapePress`, I had to create a new wrapper `Modal` component that uses `StyledModal` component under the hood. It is here that the code to detect key and mouse press resides.

Here are some snippets of code to explain my approach:

**Modal.js** (snippets)

```jsx
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.closeOnClickOutside &&
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", this.handleClick, false);
  this.props.closeOnEscape &&
    document.addEventListener("keyup", this.handleKeyPress, false);
}
render() {
  return (
    <StyledModal
      style={{ display: this.props.show ? "block" : "none" }}
      ref={this.modal}
    >
      <Wrapper>{this.props.children}</Wrapper>
    </StyledModal>
  );
}
```

**StyledModal.jsx**

```
import styled from "styled-components";

const StyledModal = styled.div`
  position: fixed;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: grey;
  z-index: 1;
`;

export default StyledModal;
```

**index.js** (Intended Usage)

```
<Modal
  show={this.state.isOpen}
  closeOnEscape
  onClose={() => this.setState({ isOpen: false })}
>
  <Header>I have a nice title</Header>
  <Body>But not much to say...</Body>
  <Footer>
    <button onClick={this.toggleModal}>Cancel</button>
    <button onClick={this.toggleModal}>OK</button>
  </Footer>
</Modal>
```

### [Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/38w3rqprq5)